# Open (edit) multiple files from within with the command mode

Tags: vim, edit

How can you open multiple files when you're already browsing one?

If I do:

```
:e myFile
```

then myFile open in another buffer, but obviously:

```
:e myFile1 myFile2
```

open a new file named "myFile1 myFile2"...

It's easily possible to open from outside, be it in tabs or buffer, but from inside, still did not find...

Comment: Try `:e myFile1 | e myFile2`, or `:tabedit myFile1 | tabedit myFile2`.

Comment: Thanks! It appears it's totally what I wanted to do :)

Answer (score 5):

`:e` and its relatives only accept *one* argument. See `:help :args`:

```
:argadd myFile1 myFile2
```

or:

```
:next myFile1 myFile2
```

You can use wildcards too:

```
:argadd *.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

lets say you have opened one file using vim named a.c

now go to command mode.
use sp (split)
example:

:sp b.c

This should work for you.
You can traverse through different files by pressing ctrl + (two times w)

Comment: Thank you! I knew the tab / split mode; it works but I wanted to open it directly into buffers without having to put it into another window / tab.